# how to display the api data using jsreport studio

Tags: node.js, jsrender, jsreport

```
Html Code:

     <h3>Hello Welcome</h3>

    <div>{{jsonData}}</div>

Script Code:

        function beforeRender(req, res, done) {
        require('request')({ 
          url:'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?        lat=35&lon=139&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1', 
          json:true,
          method: 'GET'
        }, function(err, response, body){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
            req.data = { jsonData: body };
            done();
        });


    }



The api is returns following Json Data:
{
"coord": {
    "lon": 139.01,
    "lat": 35.02
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 285.514,
    "pressure": 1013.75,
    "humidity": 100,
    "temp_min": 285.514,
    "temp_max": 285.514,
    "sea_level": 1023.22,
    "grnd_level": 1013.75
},
"wind": {
    "speed": 5.52,
    "deg": 311
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 0
},
"dt": 1485792967,
"sys": {
    "message": 0.0025,
    "country": "JP",
    "sunrise": 1485726240,
    "sunset": 1485763863
},
"id": 1907296,
"name": "Tawarano",
"cod": 200
```

}

This is the jsreport generation code. Now am trying to get the data through the rest api. I don't know how the api data is print in console, i need help to how to iterate using jsrender following json data and display in console.

Answer (score 0):

the out will comes in all the jsreport http ajax in following object in script section

"jsreport.data"

In this object will have all our data. you just print the following code in script

console.log("data is available are :",jsreport.data);